# Wordpress mod_rewrite not working on php fpm

Tags: php, server

Today I tried to change the webserver to php fpm and it is really very fast

But there is a very serious problem I found when I installed Wordpress, when I changed the premalink to anything but the normal, it not working and gives me "404 error" 

I don't know what is the problem, Is it a server problem or worpdress ?

I'm the server admin and I using CWP but don't know what to do

Answer (score 1):

It was a nginx config problem

Solved it by adding this line to .conf file

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your

> .htaccess file for apache server

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

file and check if you have updated PHP version. 
For more info, you can refer to WordPress [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

If still, you face issue then try  .user.ini files analogue to .htaccess